# Adding new element after n items in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am looking for a Java (Android) method to add a new element after every n items. The example is as following: I have two different types of items implementing same base class, let's say A and B. What I would like to achieve is to add item from an array (of B elements) to another array (of A elements) after every, let's say, 10 items. I can achieve it by implementing loop logic, but looking for some built-in functionality. Thank for your help.

**DETAILS:**

```
ArrayList<A> aList = new ArrayList<A>(Arrays.asList(a, a, a, a, a, a, a));

ArrayList<B> bList = new ArrayList<B>(Arrays.asList(b, b, b);
```

What I would like to achive is add element from "bList" to "aList" after every 3rd element of "aList" without replacing items in "aList". So my desired ArrayList is like:

```
ArrayList<A> aList = new ArrayList<A>(Arrays.asList(a, a, a, b, a, a, a, b, a, b));
```

Comment: You need to provide more details. For example write pseudocode with expected functionality.

Comment: How is this an android question though?

Comment: Is this school problem, or Yoy have another practical goal? Or this is XY problen

Comment: @JacekCz Just trying to find more practical solution

Answer (score 4):

Tested with strings:

```
    ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"));

    ArrayList<String> bList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("b", "b", "b"));

    int step = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < bList.size(); i++) {
        int index = (step + 1) * (i + 1) - 1;

        if (index < aList.size()) {
            aList.add(index, bList.get(i));
        } else {
            aList.add(bList.get(i));
        }
    }

    for (String x : aList) {
        System.out.print(x);
    }
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort. Actually, I'm able to achieve it with loop, looking for something built-in like `sort` in `Collections`. "I can achieve it by implementing loop logic, but looking for some built-in functionality"

Comment: @FARID why? You can't achieve that with sorting, how would you even write the comparator for that?

Comment: I'm not saying using `sort`. I just referenced `sort` as a built-in method so we don't have to manually sort any `ArrayList`. I just gave it as an example. So, I am just looking for some built-in method to achieve what I asked in the question. Didn't have high expectation of the existence of such method, but thought maybe there is something like that

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe such a method exists. You could use a different approach, like:

Creating an inner class that extends the ArrayList class and overriding the `add()` method to change an inner global variable (so that you don't declare it final), Declare a method called "specialAdd" or something and make it return a Boolean 
It will have this line of code at the bottom: `return super.add(o);`
and the method should also increment the global variable you defined earlier and when if it equals three you will add the desired element from bList to aList.

Answer (score -2):

If I understood, you have a common class : `BaseClass`, and two class that extends `Baseclass`, `ClassA` and `ClassB`.
To do such array, just create an array of type Baseclass : `ArrayList<BaseClass>` and write a static method like you said to loop (I do not think there is a built-in method, but not sure) and add ClassA then ClassB, or if you have an array of A type, you can add it using `.addAll()` method.

I cannot seem to find a way without looping.

Comment: Actually your answer is kinda re-iteration of my question :))